# How can I define if my input has the value x?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where I try to define if the value of my input is equal with an email to do something. But it never recognise the right value.

Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/koo29obw/

```
$('.signInButton').on('click', function(){
    if($('input[name=email]').val() == 'email@gmail.com'){
       console.log('holla');
    }else{
       console.log('nope');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is incorrect. It should be `email_username`. So change this:

```
$('input[name=email')
```

to this:

```
$('input[name=email_username]')
```

```js
$('.signInButton').on('click', function() {
  if ($('input[name=email_username]').val() == 'email@gmail.com') {
    console.log('holla');
  } else {
    console.log('nope');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="signInInput" name="email_username" placeholder="Email or Username" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}"/>
<div class="signInButton">Sign In</div>
```